# Is it possible to trace WebSQL commands in browser's console?

Tags: web-sql

When developing and debugging a web application that uses Web SQL database, sometimes it's not trivial to figure out what SQL commands are executed.

Is it possible to trace WebSQL commands into browser's console as they run?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented simple library that does exactly that - prints out each SQL command to console.

That's the library:
https://github.com/terikon/webSqlTracer

Include it on your page, and as you want trace data to appear, run

```
webSqlTracer.traceOnOpen('YourDatabaseName');
```

It will print each SQL command in following format:

```
SQL TRACE YourDatabaseName: 'INSERT INTO foo (id, text) VALUES (1, "websqltracer is cool")'
```